# Remove a string from a list based on that string containing a certain character

Tags: python, arrays, string, list

How do you write a function that removes a string from an array if that string contains a certain character

For an example you would be removing all strings that contain an 'a'.

```
my_list = ["apples", "plums", "oranges", "lemons"]
```

Comment: `filtered_list = [i for i in my_list if 'a' not in i]`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as follows:

```
def get_filtered_list(my_list, sub_string):
    return [string for string in my_list if sub_string not in string]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with *list comprehension* or a simple `for` loop, the key is you want to check `if 'a' not in something`, if there is an `a` you don't want it

```
print([i for i in my_list if 'a' not in i])
```

Expanded:

```
for i in my_list:
    if 'a' not in i:
        print(i)
```